# ASME Template (overleaf)/ unbale to print pagenumber

Tags: page-numbering, overleaf, templates, overleaf-toolkit

I have finished my writting in ASME( a scientific journal) template provided by overleaf. However i am unable to print page number. I have tried following
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

but still does not work

Can someone please suggest something ?

Best Wishes
Sidharath Madaan

Comment: Use `\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt, cleanfoot]{asme2ej}`

Comment: @SimonDispa Thank you very much. It worked